TIN interpolation results are inconclusive in QGIS

I have a series of survey points I have extracted the X,Y,Z table data into a point layer successfully. But when I try and use the TIN Interpolation tool to create a raster from these points the analysis is completed in 0.6 seconds which is far quicker than I would expect. And the result I get has a massive range of values for both the maximum and minimum values of the color ramp.
When looking at the attribute table in making the points, all the X,Y,Z data was converted to text strings, I believe this may be the problem. But the points are all plotting correctly onto a base map, so they are geographically correct. What is causing this issue?
